# Connecting MySQL database to Ionic/Angular application

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, mariadb

I am developing an Ionic/Angular application and I am struggling to connect it to my MySQL database (mariadb) . I have tried several solutions found on the web, but I keep getting a ton of error messages. I am seeking advice on the best way to connect my MySQL database to my Ionic/Angular application. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

imagine that my database is on server 11.11.111.111, that my database is called products and my table items, that my password is 1234 and my username hain.

I have created a page connection.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { createPool, Pool } from 'mariadb';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConnectionService {
  private pool: Pool = createPool({
    host: '11.11.111.111',
    user: 'hain',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'products',
    connectionLimit: 5
  });

  constructor() { }

  getItems(): Promise<any> {
    return this.pool.getConnection()
      .then(conn => {
        return conn.query("SELECT * FROM items")
          .then(rows => {
            conn.release();
            return rows;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            conn.release();
            throw err;
          })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  }
}
```

and I have the page tab2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ConnectionService } from '../services/connection.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
 export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  product: any;

  constructor(private connectionService: ConnectionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ConnectionService.getItems().then((data) => {
      this.product = data;
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

}
```

I get this type of error :

```
    ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/caching-sha2-password-auth.js:2:11-24 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in …
[ng]
[ng] ./node_modules/mariadb/lib/cmd/handshake/auth/ed25519-password-auth.js:4:15-32 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in …
```

i put this on package.json

```
 "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "net": false,
    "tls": false,
    "os": false,
    "zlib": false,
    "crypto": false
  }
```

after research I tried to set up a webpack.config.js but without success.

I'm not absolutely looking to continue on my path, if you have a more efficient or secure way to operate a mariadb database, I'm open to all solutions.

Comment: have you tried successfully to connect with any other tool?

Comment: no, i don't have much knowledge in this area, do you have any idea of a tool i can research and test?

Comment: I am not sure what environment you have so our primary goal to avoid connectivity issues. If you are following any step-by-step guides then probably they may include any other connectivity advices.

Comment: _"I keep getting a ton of error messages."_ - so why haven't you posted them here?

Comment: yes sorry, I'm not used to it, I have modified

Answer (score 0):

A lot of new developers make the same mistake: they try to connect to their database directly from their front end. **This is a huge security vulnerability** and should not be ever done, no matter what kind of project that is.

Your database connection should **always** happen on the back-end (server-side). The front-end (or client-side) should send a request to the server, asking to retrieve some data from the DB. Then, the server should respond with the data from the DB. This is the only secure way of doing things.

Now, as you seem to be new here, I think I should explain why that is. Your connection data, such as the host, user, and password should stay secret, and only accessible by the website's admin. Having all of that on the front-end exposes everything to the general public, allowing everyone to access them and thus connect to your database. It is then only the matter of time until someone deletes or leaks all your data.

Also, if you don't already know, all the website's front-end code can be inspected and freely downloaded and copied. Just click the right mouse button, select "Inspect", go to the "Source" tab in the newly opened window, and there you go: all the code before your eyes.

---

And as for the errors, I really can't tell what might be the problem. Are you sure you placed your `browser` thing in the correct file, and in the root, not inside of any other field? Other than that, I'm of no use here.

---

Also, I spotted a typo in your `ngOnInit`: it should be `this.connectionService` instead of `this.ConnectionService` (notice the capital C). If you didn't already fix that, here you go.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Hi, yes this is very useful, I will try to do some research on the back-end (server-side). I prefer to do things properly. Thank you very much!